# How AWS Secrets Manager secures credentials when it requires an ARN in plaintext in app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, cryptography, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to allow my app to connect to a client's remote MariaDB backend, without including the connection details in plaintext inside my app's code.

As I use other AWS services, I naturally checked out Secrets Manager to solve the issue of the app being able to be decompiled and the plaintext credentials being extracted... AWS Secrets Manager stores the credentials encrypted on AWS and when my app provides the ARN over the Internet, AWS decrypts and sends back the credentials to my app.

This is all good and fine and 'prevents' the plaintext decompiling risk, or does it? The issue I am struggling with is the idea of "kicking the can down the road". If one were to decompile my app and obtain the ARN, couldn't they just use this and then obtain the credentials from their own call to Secrets Manager?

What I must be missing is the authentication mechanism of Secrets Manager and how it can authtenticate a call from my app, vs a call from a bad actor?

If anyone else has been in a similar position and can clear this up I greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

TL;DR - Secrets manager requires an ARN passed to it, which is an authentication string, isn't this just like having a password in the app? One could use the ARN to obtain the password just kicking the can down the road, no?

Comment: Your app, and any potential attacker, needs AWS credentials for your account to retrieve your secrets from Secrets Manager. An ARN is not an authentication mechanism. It's a resource identifier. The ARN identifies which secret. The requesting identity must still have the necessary permission for the underlying secret.

Comment: @jarmod how does the app keep the credentials for AWS safe then if they are required in the app to get Secrets? Thanks!

Comment: If your app runs in AWS then it typically gets temporary, auto-rotated AWS credentials because it was launched with an IAM role. Those credentials give you access to the relevant secret stored in Secrets Manager. How you secure your own application is your responsibility, but AWS provides you with lots of primitives such as VPC, security groups, etc. Decompiling your app, assuming that's possible, would not help an attacker because it doesn't statically contain any credentials. It gets AWS credentials at launch time and it uses those at runtime to dynamically retrieve secrets.

Comment: @jarmod that is assuming my app runs from AWS, it's a standalone Android app, so it's outside of AWS.

Comment: You might consider inserting an application server between mobile app and database, as is common practice, for exactly this reason. The app server would expose an API and make database calls on behalf of authenticated clients. If you really want to expose a database on the internet (generally not a best practice) and you want a mobile app to connect directly to it then you’re going to have to work out some secure way to get credentials dynamically, via an authenticated request to a backend, probably.